# How to override user accent color in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, themes

I used [Fluent XAML Theme Editor](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/10/10/fluent-xaml-theme-editor-preview-released/) app to generate theme resources for my app.

My dark color scheme is black/grey with orange accent.

When I set accent color to green in Windows 10 Settings (see image below), this accent color comes through in some places.

[image: Windows Color Theme Settings]

As green and orange don't go well together, this looks really bad. How can I ensure that this does not happen?

Other similar questions on SO have answers that do NOT work for me (please do not mark as duplicate).

This is what I have done.

In Resource Dictionary I have defined orange accents for my "Dark" theme. This was generated by Fluent XAML Theme Editor (both accent and overrides are shades of orange):

```
<Windows10version1809:ColorPaletteResources Accent="#FFCC4D11"...
<!-- Override system generated accent colors -->
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark1">#FFD4632D</Color>
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark2">#FFDC7949</Color>
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorDark3">#FFE58E66</Color>
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight1">#FFB93E0E</Color>
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight2">#FFA62F0A</Color>
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColorLight3">#FF932107</Color>
```

I have also added this as suggested elsewhere on SO:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="#FFCC4D11" />
```

However, none of this works and Windows Settings green comes through anyway. For example, an accent button appears green on mouse hover. Green also appears in combo boxes and radio buttons on mouse hover.

The button is defined like this:

```
  <Button Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" Content="Start"/>
```

This is what it looks like without and with hover. You don't need to be a graphic designer to know this is a bad look. I would like a different shade of orange to appear on hover. These shades are defined in the resource dictionary as `SystemAccentColorDark1` - `SystemAccentColorLight3`, but they seem to be ignored for some reason.

How can I enforce my accent colors consistently? Obviously I do not want to have to re-style each control, I just want the colors from the resource dictionary to be used consistently.

[image: Accent button with and without mouse hover]

**UPDATE**

System accent color is coming through even in Fluent XAML Theme Editor App itself, although not for the "Accent Button" but for "Check Box" and some other controls. See image where lime highlight is visible when mouse hovers over check box.

[image: System Accent Color in Fluent XAML Theme Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

In my `app.xaml` I had this for WinUI controls:

```
 <Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In each page I had a color theme as a resource dictionary.

```
   <Page.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeDictionary.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
```

For some reason that does not work correctly.

When I put both in the app.xaml and removed page resources, the weird problems with accent colors disappeared.

```
   <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeDictionary.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I am now having problems with `ContentDialog`, but that's a different SO post. Something is not right with this resource merging it seems...

Answer (score 0):

According to `generic.xaml` (in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.19041.0\Generic`), the `AccentButtonStyle` uses the following for hover background:

```
AccentButtonBackgroundPointerOver
```

Which is a resource using `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush`, which is in turn using `SystemAccentColor`. This is the resource you need to override to avoid the system accent color coming through, for example:

```
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FFFF00</Color>
```

If you put this resource in a global location (like in `Application.xaml`), it should override the accent colour everywhere.

I'm still not sure why the accent colour generated by Fluent Theme editor is not being applied though.

I have tested this on a simple blank app - `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
   <Button Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

And `App.xaml`:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App8.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App8">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF0000</Color>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I cannot add SystemAccentColor, it says it is already defined in this scope. I think this is it: <Windows10version1809:ColorPaletteResources Accent="#FFCC4D11" (.Net adds words "System" and "Color" to "Accent"). The thing is, the accent color itself is working. I can apply it in code and in XAML. The problem is with all the related shades of the accent color that are supposed to be used for hover and the like are coming through as Windows OS accent color (in my example shades of green).

Comment: @under That is very curious. I am unable to replicate the problem. Could you make a small blank app that demonstrates the problem and put it on GitHub? I would love to take a look

Comment: The problem is with NavigationView control it seems. I cannot replicate it with a simple project, only in navigation view pages. I've uploaded the project here: https://github.com/under3415/TestThemeAccent2

Comment: did you have a chance to have a look at the project on GitHub?

Comment: @under Ah, sorry, not yet. I will try to do so today, but if not, definitely remind me again :-D .

Comment: I've added another update. The system color comes through even in the Fluent XAML Theme Editor app itself, although not for accent button. Have a look at update 2 and image. How can I remove any sign of this system color?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this, is to customize the control template.

I first copy the standard control template from:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.19041.0\Generic\themeresources.xaml

into my resource dictionary.

Then I painstakingly modify the template to eradicate the offending colors. Something like this:

```
                       <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}" />
                                <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
```

This is really tedious and unnecessary work, I am not sure why is no one from MS jumping on this. It is definitely not a problem just for me, this happens in the official Fluent XAML Editor app from MS.